# WCF serviceAuthenticationManager and TransportSecurity

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, .net-4.5

I have WCF web service (.Net 4.5 RTM).

I want to provide custom IPrincipal and IIdentity inplementations, so I decided to provide custom ServiceAuthenticationManager.

Strange thing is that ServiceAuthenticationManager is instantiated, but Authenticate method is not called.

So, when I have server config like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EntityServiceBehavior">
                <serviceAuthenticationManager
                    authenticationSchemes="None"
                    serviceAuthenticationManagerType="Belrost.Communication.EntityServiceAuthenticationManager, Belrost.Communication" />
                <serviceAuthorization
                    impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false"
                    principalPermissionMode="Custom"
                    serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Belrost.Communication.EntityServiceAuthorizationManager, Belrost.Communication" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate
                        findValue="test.local"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                        storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                        storeName="My" />
                </serviceCredentials>
                <serviceDebug
                    includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"
                    httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
                    httpsHelpPageUrl="https://test.local/service/belrost-help" />
                <serviceMetadata
                    httpsGetEnabled="true"
                    httpsGetUrl="https://test.local/service/belrost-meta" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="EntityServiceBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service
            name="Belrost.Server.EntityService"
            behaviorConfiguration="EntityServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint
                address="https://test.local/service/belrost"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="EntityServiceBinding"
                bindingNamespace="http://schemas.triflesoft.org/"
                contract="Belrost.Communication.IEntityContract" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Authenticate method is called, but because of clientCredentialType="None" no authorization information is provided.

When I change None to Basic everywhere, Authenticate method is not called anymore (however breakpoint in EntityServiceAuthenticationManager constructor is hit) and I get SecurityTokenValidationException with message "LogonUser failed for the 'test' user. Ensure that the user has a valid Windows account."